# Adding quantity of shopping cart table rows items

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have the following markup in `foreach` :

```
@foreach($addedToCart as $item)
    <tr class="cart-row">
        <td>{{ $item->product->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->product->price }}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="value-button" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue()" value="Decrease Value">-</div>
            <input type="text" id="number" class="totalQuantity" value="1" />
            <div class="value-button" id="increase" class="increase" data-unit-price="{{ $item->product->price }}" onclick="increaseValue()" value="Increase Value" data-value="1">+</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <h3>Total Amount : $ <span id="totalAmount"> 0</span></h3>
</div>
```

Jquery :

```
$('#increase').on("click", function () {
    var st = 0;
    $('.cart-row').each(function () {
        var i = $('#increase', this);
        var up = $(i).data('unit-price');
        var q = $('.totalQuantity').val();
        st = st + (up * q);
    });
    $('#totalAmount').text(st);
});
```

The issue is that, It only works for only first row.
The `<tr></tr>` is in `foreach` and every tr have class `cart-row`.

What am i missing ?

Comment: You have used id="increase" like `$('#increase').on("click"` and you are doing foreach loop here so all items have the same id as per your code. That is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Its working on 1st element only because there must be only one `ID` in a DOM. If you put more than one then it will consider the 1st one from top in the DOM.

From the code you have posted, I can see that you have also binded `class` with the same name. So if you use it as a selector in your jquery code it will work fine.

```
$('.increase').on("click", function () {
    var st = 0;
    $('.cart-row').each(function (i, obj) {
        var up = $('.cart-row:eq('+i+')').find('.increase').data('unit-price');
        var q = $('.cart-row:eq('+i+')').find('.totalQuantity').val();
        st = st + (up * q);
    });
    $('#totalAmount').text(st);
});
```

Comment: If it worked well as you need, then can you please accept this answer?